# how to use case with condition inside a function in mysql?

Tags: sql, mysql

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `db_sp`$$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `bil`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `bil`(num INT) RETURNS VARCHAR(7) CHARSET latin1
BEGIN
    DECLARE result VARCHAR(7);
    CASE num
    WHEN num > 0 THEN
    SET result = "Positive";
    WHEN num < 0 THEN
    SET result = "Negative";
    ELSE SET result = "Neutral";
    END CASE;
    RETURN result;
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

when I run SELECT bil(4); the result was Neutral. I think it should've been Positive. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the [`CASE` statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/case.html) has two alternative syntaxes, and you're mixing both:

```
CASE case_value
    WHEN when_value THEN statement_list
    [WHEN when_value THEN statement_list] ...
    [ELSE statement_list]
END CASE

CASE
    WHEN search_condition THEN statement_list
    [WHEN search_condition THEN statement_list] ...
    [ELSE statement_list]
END CASE
```

It is not *wrong* per-se, it just renders incorrect results for your use case because you're comparing `num` with `num > 0` (which equals `1` when num is 4) and with `num < 0` (which equals `0`). None match, so you get to the `ELSE` clause.

Get rid of the extraneous `num` on top:

```
CASE /*num*/
    WHEN num > 0 THEN
        SET result = "Positive";
    WHEN num < 0 THEN
        SET result = "Negative";
    ELSE SET result = "Neutral";
END CASE;
```

Additionally, you need `VARCHAR(8)` rather than `VARCHAR(7)`.

[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aJhPtKzvafWMkAUDuRTgdQ/0)

*On a side note, `latin1` is a legacy encoding you should try to avoid in 2023. Switch to `utf8mb4` whenever possible. And MySQL is one of the few database engines that accept double quotes for strings, which the SQL standard reserves for identifiers—I'd suggest you get used to single quotes to avoid surprises when working with other systems.*

Comment: thanks a lot, I didn't notice that I mixed them both.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it by moving the `set` outside the `case` statement :

```
CREATE FUNCTION `bil`(num INT) 
  RETURNS VARCHAR(20) CHARSET latin1
BEGIN
    DECLARE result VARCHAR(20);
    SET result = CASE WHEN num > 0 
                        THEN "Positive" 
                      WHEN num < 0 
                        THEN "Negative" 
                      ELSE "Neutral" END;
    RETURN result;
end;
```

Comment: Moving `set` outside `case` basically means switching from case statement to case operator. Both are equally valid solutions as far as I can tell.